# unauthorized error on view django-rest-framework-social-oauth2

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, python-social-auth, django-socialauth

after successful social login i am getting redirected to the

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = "/users/ldata/"
```

but it's giving the unauthorized error

```
HTTP 401 Unauthorized
Allow: GET, HEAD, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept
WWW-Authenticate: Bearer realm="api"

{
  "detail": "Authentication credentials were not provided."
}
```

my settings.py

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
    'oauth2_provider.contrib.rest_framework.OAuth2Authentication',
    'rest_framework_social_oauth2.authentication.SocialAuthentication',
),

'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
    'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
),
}


AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
# for Google authentication
'social_core.backends.open_id.OpenIdAuth',
'social_core.backends.google.GoogleOpenId',
'social_core.backends.google.GoogleOAuth2',

#linkedin
'social_core.backends.linkedin.LinkedinOAuth',

# django-rest-framework-social-oauth2
'rest_framework_social_oauth2.backends.DjangoOAuth2',

# Django
'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
)
```

**middleware:**

'social_django.middleware.SocialAuthExceptionMiddleware',

**conbtext_processor:**

'social_django.context_processors.backends',
'social_django.context_processors.login_redirect',

**installed apps:**

'oauth2_provider',

'social_django',

'rest_framework_social_oauth2',

'rest_framework',

'users',